# Java Path not found (Batch)

Tags: java, apk, sign

I would like to compile an apk file using a batch. But if I try to sign it, it says:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
Usage: signapk [-w] publickey.x509 [.pem] privatekey.pk8 input.jar output.jar
```

The System can't find the given path.

I thought about finding an input and output file in Java and put it in at the settings, but i can't find it.
I tried to put in the java path too like given on the Internet, but that did not work.

Comment: Post your batch file; not just your error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think signapk is complaining that it cannot find its input and output file.  Try fully qualifying the path to them.

Comment: where can i find the input and output file? i already searched for them but no luck :(

Comment: The input file would be the jar file you wish to sign.  The output file would be the fully qualified path to where you want the result written to.

Comment: It may also be complaining that it doesnt know where the pem file is.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it would be good to see the code, bit i can imagine that you tried to write the path without using a variable.
Try this:
set path=#yourpath# (without the #)
You can use the variable with %path%